# Is calculating powers this way only possible by hard-coding it?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have to write a program calculating 3^14 (printing each power value out as we go). However, I can NOT use jumps or branches. I'd rather not just **mul** all the way until I hit the 14th power, unless necessary.

Is this possible without hard-coding it (keep in mind, we haven't gotten very far into the language yet). We know jumps, simple logical conditions, and branches (alongside this, the basics of the language - add, la, li, syscall, etc..)

Comment: You could probably implement "repeated squaring", but I dunno after that.

Comment: Would a recursive solution be allowed?

Comment: @KonradLindenbach A recursive solution without jumps?  No jumps and no branches to me means no evaluation of conditionals or comparisons.  If you can't `jmp`, `jne`, `jz`, etc, then there's not much to do but a rote linear solution, I think.

Comment: @J... No doubt that a recursive function would imply using `jal`, I was just wondering if it was acceptable

Comment: x*3 = x(2+1) = (x*2) + (x*1) = (x<<1)+x

Comment: @KonradLindenbach `jal` is a jump, and he said in big block letters that's not allowed.

Comment: Are you sure the instructor didn't say for you to calculate **2^14**? Because powers of 2 are trivial in MIPS: see `sll`.

Comment: I think the consensus is that, barring some clever numerical trick (maybe something gleaned from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)) you have to hard code the solution. So, to answer your question: No.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a program to write the "hard coded" program. Something like this for a c printing out c:

```
printf("int x = 3;\n");
for (i = 2; i <=14; i++) {
  printf("x = x * 3;\n");
  printf("printf(\"next power = %%d\\n\", x);\n");
}
```

This will output something like this (truncated):

```
int x = 3;
x = x * 3;
printf("next power = %d\n", x);
x = x * 3;
printf("next power = %d\n", x);
x = x * 3;
printf("next power = %d\n", x);
x = x * 3;
```

This code can then be compiled an run, and will output this (again, truncated):

```
next power = 9
next power = 27
next power = 81
next power = 243
next power = 729
next power = 2187
next power = 6561
```

You will obviously need to translate this to MIPS. Unfortunately, since your problem specifies that the code must be linear with no jumps or branches, this is the only way I can think of to write the program without having to manually type each line.